# .NET Core & C++ mixed mode debugging with WSL2

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, wsl-2, mixed-mode

Given a Visual Studio solution with 2 projects:

1. .NET Core console application (Linux)
2. C++ for Linux project (*output: Dynamic library, `.so`*)

Where #1 has a dependency on #2:

- I am able to debug #1 and #2 separately in WSL2 from Visual Studio 2019.
- The output of #2 is loaded successfully during the runtime of #1.

**Q:** Is it possible in Visual Studio 2019 to *debug #1 in mixed mode, while stepping into code in #2*? (if it's definitely not possible, knowing *that* would also be helpful)

**Note**: the 'Enable native code debugging' option doesn't appear in project #1's debug's settings

[image]

Comment: I think it could be done. Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019) and do not forget to use `DllImport` and check the option `enable native code debugging`.

Comment: And let us know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you. I've originally tried following that document. It works just fine for *other* cases. However project #1 above doesn't have the "enable native code debugging" option in its options.

Comment: Did you create a c# net core project, and that project should have this option. Close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, did it has the option?

Comment: thanks you, but - no, that doesn't change anything. i've included an image in the original message that shows this option isn't available

Comment: How did you create that project on VS?

Comment: from the "new project" wizard -> "Console App (.NET Core)". also using the ".NET Core Debugging with WSL 2 - Preview" extension: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/debug-your-net-core-apps-in-wsl-2-with-visual-studio/

Comment: just noticed the 'qna' section for that extension has this: *"Is mixed mode debugging c++ and c# components of a vs 2019 solution going to be natively supported in wsl2 ?"* -> *"This is not currently on our roadmap, but it's something we'll continue to evaluate for the future.'*. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.Dot-Net-Core-Debugging-With-Wsl2&ssr=false#qna